# Sum of the Poisson distribution (my solution vs. textbook)

Tags: summation, poisson-distribution, moment-generating-functions

I feel something is wrong, but can't place it:

> Assume $X_i$ are i.i.d. Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$
>   and define
>
> $$Y = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i $$
>
> $$M_X(t) = \exp((e^t-1)\cdot\lambda)$$
>
> $$M_Y(t) = \Big({\exp((e^t-1)\cdot\lambda)\Big)}^n
>              =   \exp((e^t-1)\cdot n\cdot\lambda)$$

where $M_X(\cdot)$ is [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function).

so I think $$f_Y(y)=\text{The pdf of }Y = {e^{-n\lambda}(n\lambda)^y\over y!}$$

but in my textbook  $$f_Y(y) = {e^{-n\lambda}(\lambda)^y\over y!}$$

I don't understand it!

Is there something wrong in my solution?

or

is the textbook wrong?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. The site uses MathJax for displaying mathematical formulas. You should visit https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to format your question. It will be far easier to read, and you'll get more answers.

Comment: What is $f(y)$?

Comment: Your book seems made a mistake